# Building"MyApplication" gradle info

Tags: android

i am stuck on android studio 2.3.3, it just runs forever without showing any process ahead. Same for new project and importing old ones

Comment: Please describe in detail

Comment: Add your code with error

Comment: Restart Android Studio and see if the issue remains. It happend a few times to me and restarting Android Studio made the trick.

Comment: after installing studio 2.3.3.  I created a new project with all default settings then the "  Building 'MyApplication' Gradle info " popped up and stuck there without any futher runnning just stuck for infinte time

Answer (score 0):

Wait for at least 30-40 min if the process remain same uninstall studio completely and reinstall studio and then try to create new project, Hope it may help you.